# Delete some part of a row from database ( a value in a set of the daatabase row )

Tags: php, mysql, sql-delete, find-in-set

I want to delete a part of my row in mysql. like this:

my row: 1,2,3,4

I want to make it: 1,2,3

how can I do that?

I know it can be done with this code but is there a better way?

`UPDATE Table SET message = REPLACE(message, ",4", "") WHERE id = 1;`

Comment: values 1,2,3,4 are in one column right ?

Comment: It would be good if u update column  e.g UPDATE Table SET message = "1,2,3" WHERE id = 1;

Comment: `UPDATE Table SET message = "1,2,3" WHERE id = 1;`

try this...

Comment: @KanishkaPanamaldeniya yeah

Comment: @annampriyatam and if the value bee too much , I should write all of that??? a way that I be able to do that using `DELETE`

Comment: What is the condition? Is there anything more than replacing the string '1,2,3,4' with '1,2,3' ? What if the string is 6,7,8,9 ?

Comment: yeah. maybe It changes to 1,5,7,1,2,42 and ... . That is not as short to write all of that!

Comment: So you want to skip 4 from your string if 4 comes alone, am I?

Comment: @usermesam0023 yes. 4 plus "," before it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So this will work.

```
UPDATE Table SET message = CASE
WHEN message LIKE '4,%'
THEN // enter code here to replace '4,' in message with ''
WHEN message LIKE '%,4,%'
THEN // enter code here to replace ',4,' in message with ','
WHEN message LIKE '%,4'
THEN // enter code here to replace ',4' in message with ''
ELSE // this means all other occurances of 4 like 14,41,44,etc do nothing here or skip this else condition
END;
```

Answer (score 0):

For security fistly you test code in test server.

İf you'll replace ,4 , mysql will replace ,40 too

you must change string

,1,2,3,4,

and you must replace ,4,

Comment: That's why he uses the ID in WHERE condition :)